# Multiple NOT LIKE in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like

```
+--------+-------+
| id     | name  |
+--------+-------+
| 302345 | Name1 |
| 522345 | Name2 |
| 1X2345 | Name3 |
| 2X2345 | Name4 |
| 1X8765 | Name5 |
| 2X2123 | Name6 |
| 502345 | Name7 |
| M62345 | Name8 |
+--------+-------+
```

I want to take id that doesn't have prefix `30`,`1X`,`2X`. Like this I have more than 20 prefix to be excluded. I was using `NOT LIKE` 20 times and looking to shorten it. From some of stackoverflow question, I have found we can create a table and store all these values in a column and use that. But in my case I don't have permission to create table. Hence tried the below code but it is giving strange results.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT '30%' Prefix
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '50%'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '1X%'
    ) list ON id NOT LIKE prefix
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3bf7373fd9caa89f36ee93cce4284df) . Please suggest some alternative.

Expected output

```
+--------+-------+
| id     | name  |
+--------+-------+
| 522345 | Name2 |
+--------+-------+
| 502345 | Name7 |
+--------+-------+
| M62345 | Name8 |
+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS` with a `VALUES` construct for all your prefixes.

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable mt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM (VALUES('30%'),('50%'),('1X%'),('2X%')/*,...*/)V(expr)
                  WHERE mt.id LIKE V.expr);
```

Comment: Considering that the they are prefixes as well, @M.Ali the query will still be SARGable as well, which is always a nice benefit. :)