# SQL Server - Python - How to use the wildcard % in tuple for where statement?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am using Python and SQL Server to get a query with following specifications:

The original query I want to run (without the use of tuples):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_1 LIKE '%option1%' or COLUMN_1 LIKE '%option2%'
```

I would like to create a tuple that contains all the selection options:

```
options = ('%option1%', '%option2%')

"SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_1 in {options}".format(options = options)
```

However, somehow, this does not seem to run properly. Can anyone help me with the correct statements?

Comment: Are you certain that you would always have exactly two `LIKE` expressions in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: No, that is the reason I want something dynamically. So, that if the input changes to for example five possibilities in the "options" variable, that the query still works.

Comment: Then you have to build the `WHERE IN (...)` clause dynamically, with the correct number of placeholders.  Then bind a tuple of the correct length.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Okay, how do I do that? :-)

Comment: You said it doesn't run properly.  What is wrong with the query...it looks valid to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I run the original query, I get 320 rows. When I use the query with the tuple and the format option, then I get 670 rows.

Comment: I assume in the "real world" scenario you're going to have more than 2 values? If not, then just stick the the `OR`.

Comment: @Larnu: In real world, I need to run this query over 100 times. And for each time, the number of values for "options" can vary between 2 - 22.

Comment: You *could* use a table-type parameter, and then an `EXISTS`, like a demonstrate in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63899602/2029983) (of course, not using a `NOT`).

Comment: @Larnu: FROM (VALUES('30%'),('50%'),('1X%'),('2X%')/*,...*/)V(expr), but how do I vary that then across for 2 - 22 types of values without adjusting the actual query?

Comment: "*You could use a table-type parameter,"* you would need to change the query; but you do that already in the above. `IN` and `=` are not the same operators. And `C1 LIKE @A OR C1 LIKE @B` is not equivalent to `C1 IN (@A,@B)` when `@A` or `@B` contain wild cards.

Comment: @Larnu: Really, thank you for your help. But I need it a bit more written out as I am not a good SQL user... Could you rewrite my sql statement above with what you are telling. Because, I can't seem to get it to work on my own. Would help me a lot, searching to get this to work already for more than 1 day...

Comment: Although I could, I would be unable to provide the python side of things for how to use a table type parameter, so any answer I give would likely be incomplete; unless you know how to define a table type parameter for SQL Server in Python already?

Comment: @Larnu: I found a solution myself :-) Thanks for your help, because of your suggestions I tried other things and therefore found a solution. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to achieve with a for-loop:

```
options = ('%option1%', '%option2%')

items = ''
for option in options:
    if options.index(option) == 0: 
       items = items + " COLUMN_1 LIKE '" + option + "'"
    else: 
       items = items + " or COLUMN_1 LIKE '" + option + "'"


query = "SELECT *
         FROM TABLE_A
         WHERE {items}".format(items= items)
```

In this way you can add how many options you want and your query will still run in a correct manner.